# HTML mailto with line breaks not working with android chrome

Tags: html, mailto

How to add line breaks in html mailto?

I have tried %0D%0A it works fine but if I tried the above code with android browser it displays as it is. Also in chrome android the spaces replaced as +. Any alternatives / solution for my problem?

I have used the code below,

`<a href="mailto:recipient@example.com?subject=When%2C%20when%20is%20now%3F%20">Click me</a>`

`<a href="mailto:recipient@example.com?subject=Test Subject">Click me</a>`

`<a href="mailto:endpointadress@something.com?cc=endpointadress2@something.com&amp;subject=your subject&amp;body=Text before new line.%0D%0AText after new line.">create email</a>`

Comment: show what you have done?

Comment: `I have tried %0D%0A`..... The question shows what has been tried and what the outcome was....

Answer (score 0):

If its the subject jsut escape the test like so:

var link = "mailto:Adviser@helpme.com&subject=" + escape("[AEP] Processing Request");
window.location.href = link;

Comment: The code not working with android chrome